# Check if a record with the same unique ID exists in SQL table before insert

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I check if there's another record in the table with the same unique ID (the column name is `ID`), then and if one exists not do anything, otherwise insert the record?

Do I need to index the `ID` column and set it as unique/primary key?

Comment: 1) use `insert into a(key1,...) value1,... where not exists (select 1 from a where key1=value1)` 2) you don't _need_ the index, but it would surely help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use `INSERT IGNORE`. As the name implies it will INSERT rows that do not exist, and it will do nothing with duplicate rows.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
`id` int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
`foo` varchar(20) 
);

INSERT IGNORE INTO Table1
    (`id`, `foo`)
VALUES
    (1, 'a'),
    (2, 'a'),
    (3, 'a'),
    (4, 'a'),
    (1, 'a'),
    (2, 'a'),
    (1, 'a');
```

The above will only insert the first 4 rows. The final 3 rows are not inserted because they have duplicate keys.

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0d00/1)

`INSERT IGNORE` requires that you have either a primary key or unique index.

More info on `INSERT IGNORE` (as well as other ways to handle duplicates) here: [MySQL Handling Duplicates](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-handling-duplicates.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You may use `REPLACE` as `INSERT OR UPDATE` for that

Comment: Not sure that's what the OP wants, as those operations *will* change the data. The OP wants nothing to happen if the ID already exists.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to change it to also do something when the id alreadt exists, here's a snippet:

```
INSERT INTO table (key1, ...) VALUES (value1, ...) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE dosomethingelse
```

So if the key already exists it will update whatever is after `on duplicate key`, else it will insert whatever is before that.